# Attaching Theme Library to Custom Module

Tags: theming, javascript

I have a subtheme called `bootstrap_subtheme`. It has a library called `global-styling`. I created a custom module called `telephone_alter`. In `telephone_alter.module`, I have the following:

```
function telephone_alter_form_user_form_alter(&$form){
  $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'bootstrap_subtheme/global_styling';
}
```

it does not load the `bootstrap_subtheme` library stylesheet. I do `dump($form)` and get the following:

```
  "#attached" => array:1 [▼
    "placeholders" => array:1 [▼
      "form_action_p_pvdeGsVG5zNF_XLGPTvYSKCf43t8qZYSwcfZl2uzM" => array:1 [▼
        "#lazy_builder" => array:2 [▶]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

seems like the attachment isn't even grabbing it. Yes I am using the right form alter according to the api: hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() and my ID is `user_form` . It does fire off, if I attach css from within my module's folder, but not my subtheme. Any help would be great! Thank you.

One more note:

my `root` dir is as follows:

```
modules
   -telephone_alter
theme:
   contrib:
      -bootstrap
   custom:
      -bootstrap_subtheme
```

Here is bootstrap_subtheme.libraries.yml:

```
global-styling:
  js:
    js/popper.min.js: {}
    js/bootstrap.min.js: {}
    js/global.js: {}
  css:
    component:
      css/style.css: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
```

Comment: Show us your `bootstrap_subtheme.libraries.yml` file too

Comment: @beltouche editted the post to include bootstrap_subtheme.libraries.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on that structure, you're referencing the library incorrectly.
It should be `$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'bootstrap_subtheme/bootstrap_subtheme.global-styling';`

As noted in a comment below, the duplicate use of the theme name may not be necessary, and `$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'bootstrap_subtheme/global-styling';` should work according to the docs. (Note the use of a dash, matching the library name versus an underscore in your code.)

Comment: This is not true, the syntax used in the question is correct. It is simply `module_name/library_name`. No need to repeat the module name after the slash.

Comment: Interesting. Every case I've had in my experience, I have the module name there, although I see in the docs, there's no requirement for it.
It just be the author's use of an underscore versus a hyphen then.

Comment: @Hudri @beltouche it was the simple hyphen in `global-styling` that was my mistake